# Gráfico pelo ggplot no RStudio v 1.1.463 não lê o subtitle e o caption em labs()

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estou com o problema relatado no título e, não entendo por que no RStudio o subtitle e o caption não são lidos. Quando replico o código no Visual Studio, ele carrega corretamente todos os comandos - o gráfico fica exatamente como está no código.

Segue o código e um trecho dos dados para replicar no RStudio:

```
ggplot(Endividamento_Familias_Mensal, aes(Data, 
Endividamento_Familias)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(title = "Endividamento Familiar", caption = "Fonte: PNADC - 
Bacen")
```

Os dados são:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este mesmo código, com estes mesmos dados, executados pelo Visual Studio, gera o gráfico corretamente.

Veja como fica pelo RStudio:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Neste caso, é o caption que não aparece.... O subtitle não coloquei neste caso.

Comment: Poste os dados da série temporal, não o print dela.

Comment: Pode, por favor, **editar a pergunta** com a saída de `dput(Endividamento_Familias_Mensal)` ou, se a base for muito grande, de `dput(head(Endividamento_Familias_Mensal, 20))`?

Comment: Na minha máquina `caption` funciona corretamente, veja aqui: [https://imgur.com/a/di3nWH9](https://imgur.com/a/di3nWH9). Sugiro a você atualizar `ggplot2` bem como checar a sua versão do `R`. Entre `sessionInfo()` no console em RStudio. O meu `ggplot2` é versão 2.2.1 e `R` versão 3.5.0.

Comment: Tente `Endividamento_Familias_Mensal$Data <- as.Date(Endividamento_Familias_Mensal$Data, "%d/%m%/Y")`. Se a coluna `data` for um objeto de classe `"Date"`, comigo funciona na perfeição.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O argumento `caption` foi inserido no [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2) versão 2.2, que é de novembro de 2016 ([fonte](https://blog.rstudio.com/2016/11/14/ggplot2-2-2-0/)).

Conforme alguns comentários, não se trata de um erro no RStudio. O mais provável, sem conhecer a `sessionInfo()`, é que a versão utilizada do R pelo shell do Visual Studio e no RStudio sejam diferentes e que nesta última o ggplot2 disponível seja de uma versão inferior a 2.2.

Você pode verificar a versão do [r](/questions/tagged/r) que está sendo usada no RStudio com o começando `R.version[["version.string"]]`. É possível alterar a versão utilizada no RStudio no menu `Tools` > `Global Options...`. Na aba `General` escolha a versão do `R` desejada.

Para verificar a versão do `ggplot2` que está sendo utilizada, basta rodar `installed.packages()["ggplot2", "Version"]`. Certifique-se que o número seja maior do que "2.2".

Comment: Tomás, muito obrigado. Realmente era a versão do ggplot2 no RStudio. Ótimo ano novo e sucesso e prosperidade para você e sua família.

Comment: De nada. Aceite a resposta para auxiliar usuários que busquem informação no futuro.